# Feedback resistor not close to the op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

When building the following circuit (front-end for an audio line-level mixer), for aesthetic and ergonomic reasons, I will need to split the circuit between two PCBs, one with the jack connectors, and one with the controls (highlighted in pink). Those two PCB will be at a distance of about 5-6 cm, probably connected with a flat cable (and MicroMatch connectors).

So I'm now wondering what part of the circuit should be closer to the "jack" PCB and what to the "controls" PCB.

It would be better for me to put the whole circuit on the "jack" PCB because I would have much more physical space to layout out a nice and clean PCB, whereas on the "controls" PCB I would need to stuff everything very closely.

If I choose to do so, than means only the gain potentiometer and the two switches would be placed on the "controls" PCB (along with the rest of the circuit not shown here for simplicity). I'm not worried about the two switches, because the signals connected to them should be low impedance, coming from the opamp outputs.

But what about the GAIN potentiometer connection? Is that a sensible node (for noise, distortion, etc.)? Is it a bad idea to keep the potentiometer far from the op-amp? I once saw a similar schematic and the feedback gain potentiometer was wired with a shielded cable.

[image]

Edit: I updated the schematic with a little correction: R11, R12, R13 and R16 are now 2.1 kΩ and not 10 kΩ, so the 10 kΩ potentiometer should provide about -/+20 dB gain. Also, rails voltages are +/-15 V.

Comment: I don't think locating the pot on a separate PCB will be a problem. The gain is low enough as far as I can see, and the voltage levels are high enough. So, a potential noise coming from *long(?)* wires will not be much of a problem. Years ago I designed and made a guitar amplifier. The overdrive section was on a separate PCB located ~5 cm above the main PCB. Input, output and control (pot, just like shown in your circuit) wires were coming from/to the main board. Even though the gain was relatively higher there, I didn't have any "audible" problems.

Comment: In addition to the gain and voltage levels that Rohat mentions, you also need to consider the magnitude of the feedback resistance compared to the contact and wiring resistances. With normal op amp circuits and wires that aren't kilometers long this is a non-issue, but it might be a problem if working with a current-feedback amp. But if you're using a CFA, you probably need the extreme bandwidth that would be messed up by such a connection anyway.

Comment: What gain range are you expecting from that potentiometer?

Comment: I made a correction to the original post, the gain should be +/-20dB with the 10K potentiometer using 2.1K resistor around the pot

Comment: I would suggest a shielded cable in some cases. It would not take much coupled current to pin 1 of the gain pot to result in audible noise. If it's all inside a conductive box and takes an external well filtered DC supply (or batteries) it may not be necessary, however.

Comment: Please update the schematic @DimitriPetrucci

Comment: Why are you inverting the TIP input channel?

Comment: @Andyaka I updated the schematic, thank you. The inverting TIP approach comes from "Figure 6-26: "All Inverting" balanced line receiver" from here: https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/design-handbooks/P2%20Ch6_final.pdf